# CakePHP 2.3 Console Schema: the chosen schema could not be loaded

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a number of Plugins for my CakePHP 2.3 app which I use the schema migrations built in to maintain DB table structure.

Some of them work without a problem, but on others I get the following error:

```
Richs-MacBook-Pro:mhd rich$ ./Console/cake schema update -p PipPages
Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.0 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : mhd
Path: /Users/rich/sites/mhd/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Cake Schema Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
The chosen schema could not be loaded. Attempted to load:
File: /Users/rich/sites/mhd/Plugin/PipPages/Config/Schema/schema.php
Name: PipPage
```

I just want to point out a couple of things. My Plugin is called `PipPages`. In the output, it says it's trying to load the schema for `PipPage` - should I be naming my plugins differently?

I have triple-checked that the `schema.php` file exists for the `PipPages` plugin, but maybe the plugin should be named `PipPage` to work with the schema shell?

In the book, they give one plural example: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-configuration

Comment: The output above says its trying to load the correct plugin (plural)

Comment: ok, but the plugin folder name is plural, but the actual file class that schema is looking for is singular (the "Name: PipPage" bit from the excerpt above) - does that make sense? It's like it is expecting a singular plugin name

Comment: Good point, don't know. We've tried to integrate the migrations (plugin) into our workflow, but gave up because of its limited support for adding/modifying foreign key contraints and advanced database features.

Comment: Yes, I've just found out that it doesn't support the length attribute for a fulltext index too. There's always https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations but I had hoped I could use the built in Schema Shell without the need for another plugin

Comment: The migrations plugin doesn't offer those capabilities either (at least, last time I used it). It *has* potential, but it needs some additions (e.g. be *very* careful to use it on a live database, because when changing indexes, it may *drop* and *re-create* a column(!)). In the end we decided to stick with SQL 'delta/migration' queries for the time being and perform migrations manually

Comment: Good to know RE: dropping columns, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as if CakePHP is expecting a singular plugin name, but to get around this, you can pass the `name` param into the Schema Shell:

`./Console/cake schema update -p PipPages PipPages`

This seems to allow the update to run without errors.

Comment: This seems to be fixed as of CakePHP 2.4

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem just now relating to schemas not loading. Not to do with plugins particularly, just updating a schema in general.

```
bash-3.2$ ./Console/cake schema update -s 14

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.5 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/sites/e/example.com/public_html/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Cake Schema Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
The chosen schema could not be loaded. Attempted to load:
File: /var/sites/e/example.com/public_html/app/Config/Schema/schema_14.php
Name: App
```

`schema_14.php` was the version I wanted to upgrade to but I thought I'd try with a different one too. For some reason `schema_10.php` actually worked. It was down to the wrong class name having been added to the schema file.

**schema_10.php**

```
class AppSchema extends CakeSchema {
```

**schema_14.php**

```
class Schema extends CakeSchema {
```

Renaming `Schema` to `AppSchema` in `schema_14.php` did the trick.

Both were definitely generated using CakePHP v2.4.5. The only thing I can think of that would have caused this is `bake` being called from a different directory (i.e. with a different `-app <app>` parameter) when generating the schemas.